# NGINX Wordpress REST API block user endpoint not working

Tags: wordpress, nginx

i noticed some attacks from a bot on our wordpress login formulars with the informations that are provided by the `/wp-json/wp/v2/users` endpoint.

So I like to block these API Endpoint with NGINX.

I tried followed configuration:

```
location ~ ^/wp-json/ {
    # if permalinks not enabled
    rewrite ^/wp-json/(.*?)$ /?rest_route=/$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/wp-json/wp/v2/users {
    return 301 /?rest_route=/wp/v2/users/$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/?rest_route=/wp/v2/users {
    if ($http_cookie !~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
        return 403; # prevent access when user not logged in
    }
}
```

But for some reason it's not working. I don't see my fault in that configuration.
I hope someone can help me with this stuff.
Thanks.

Comment: 1. Regex locations are checked in order of appearance so any `/wp-json/wp/v2/users...` request will be caught by your first location block. 2. `location` directive (as well as `rewrite` one) works with the _normalized_ URI which does not include a query part, making your third location useless.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I tried now following change:

```
location ~* ^/?rest_route=/wp/v2/users {
    if ($http_cookie !~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
        return 403; # prevent access when user not logged in
    }
}
location ~* ^/wp-json/ {
    # if permalinks not enabled
    rewrite ^/wp-json/(.*?)$ /?rest_route=/$1 last;
}
```

but it will not work...

Comment: You didn't understand what I'm tried to say, did you? `location ~* ^/?rest_route=/wp/v2/users { ... }` won't work (well, it will work, but not the way you expecting), you can't check query arguments using `location` directive.